# Is there a data storage format that allows for appending columns?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, storage, dataformat

Let's assume I have a data set I want to use in Spark that contains details about users like

```
id, name, age
123, john, 23
222, Josh, 50
333, bill, 32
```

Let's say I generate/find a new fact about those users, 'email'.

```
id, email
123, john@gmail.com
222, Josh@gmail.com
333, bill@gmail.com
```

Does a storage format exist that would let me dynamically add my new fact to my old dataset without requiring a full rewrite? Basically adding an append-only column?

Comment: You may join the data

Comment: I am not sure about data format, but you can take a look on Apache Iceberg https://iceberg.incubator.apache.org/ `Iceberg adds tables to Presto and Spark that use a high-performance format that works just like a SQL table`

Comment: @Lamanus, yeah if this questions fails im just going to store the datasets in different directories and then join them manually every runtime. 
I was hoping for a different option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try KUDU Storage Manager - not a storage format. Need to be on Cloudera Stack though. Now with HortonWorks, not sure what that means though.

KUDU works well, i.e. no re-stating required. Updating possible, i.e. mutable, but non-ACID. Latter aspect not required though.

Schema evolution AVRO otherwise for Hive / HDFS.

Comment: ive heard of KUDU but never used it. ill look in to it!

Comment: It makes life a lit easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Kudu available, you can use HBase, however it's performance won't be so good if you have to perform a full-scan on the table. Its great for range/prefix search and single lookups/writes though. Also you don't need to register the schema for the table (its per-register schema)

If you have none of the above, I would just partition/bucket data and rewrite only the data which has been modified, there's no magic in any technology, most "updateable" HDFS-stored technologies will work with in-memory-deltas and then update the table (or some parts of it) in the background. You can use JSON/Map columns if you want to dynamically add columns without performing any "ALTER TABLE".

If you don't care about read time and care about write time a lot, you can just add new partitions with higher versions of the new data (which have new columns) and just keep the highest versions when reading. Or have another process removing older versions in background.

You can also write asynchronously too (no need to stop your Spark as a whole) by using multithreaded driver. Sequential writes can be very fast :) don't fear them.